# How do I trigger a Drupal-Function with Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a Checkbox with different values. When a user change the Checkbox I will trigger the Drupal-Function field_attach_update http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_update/7

I know how I check the checkbox-change with jQuery but how can I trigger the Drupal-Function then?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to check out the [Form API ajax options](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax). Specifically I think you'll want to define an ajax['callback'] function that calls field_attach_update.

```
<?php
function my_form_func($form, $form_state) {
  $my_checkbox_val = isset($form_state['values']['my_checkbox']) ? $form_state['values']['my_checkbox'] : NULL;
  $form['my_checkbox'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Check me'),
    '#default_value' => $my_checkbox_val,
    '#return_value' => $nid, // Assuming you are working with a node, but could be any entity
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'my_form_field_update_func',
      'event' => 'click',
    ),
  );
  return $form;
}

function my_form_field_update_func($form, $form_state) {
  if (isset($form_state['values']['my_checkbox'])) {
    $node = node_load($form_state['values']['my_checkbox']);
    field_attach_update('node', $node);
  }
  return $form['my_checkbox'];
}
?>
```